# PHP: how to get array based on nested value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given this array and a name (e.g. 'def'), how do I get the containing array, or key?

```
$all = array(
 '0' => array(
      'name' => 'abc'
      'option' => 1,
    ),
 '1' => array(
      'name' => 'def'
      'option' => 1,
    ),
 '2' => array(
      'name' => 'ghi'
      'option' => 0,
    ),
);
```

What's the best way to return this array given 'def'?

```
$single = array(
  'name' => 'def'
  'option' => 1,
);
```

I could do something like this:

```
$single = array();
foreach ($all as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['name'] == 'def') {
    $single = $all[$key]; 
  }
}
```

Or prerender the keys in the array so that it looks like this:

```
$all = array(
 'abc' => array(
      'name' => 'abc'
      'option' => 1,
    ),
 'def' => array(
      'name' => 'def'
      'option' => 1,
    ),
 'ghi' => array(
      'name' => 'ghi'
      'option' => 0,
    ),
);
$single = $all['def'];
```

But I'm wondering if there's a shorter php function for that.

Comment: The `foreach` method was always the best for such cases (although it would be marginally better if you include a `break` inside the `if` block). You can do it in other ways as well, but they will be more verbose, or less clear, or both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
array_filter($array, function($var){
   return $var["name"] == "def";
});
```

Comment: But you also need to unwrap the value found, so something like `list($single) = array_filter(...)` since `reset` complains if you pass in a temporary (it takes its parameter by reference). That's the best I could come up with as well, but IMHO it's too clever for its own good.

Comment: Thanks for the nice ideas! I marked this as the answer because it's the closest to a single function call as possible. Though indeed not sure I'd use it because of readablity and bit complex.